# Reverse a call to mmap()

Tags: c

I am currently reverse a challenge to learn. But why is the parameter of [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (containing `fd`) at 4294967295?

(Is it not supposed to exist? No files are open with `open`, just before.)

[image: https://snag.gy/8LPqoh.jpg]

Comment: What do you mean by *"I am currently reverse a challenge to learn."* (it seems incomprehensible)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature for `mmap` is

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
```

4294967295 is same as -1 when treated as a signed integer.

The `mmap` calls actually looks like

```
mmap(
     NULL,                                /*addr*/
     321,                                 /*length*/
     PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,  /*prot*/
     MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,         /*flags*/
     -1,                                  /*fd*/
     0                                    /*offset*/
)
```

Now as per the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap),

> **MAP_ANONYMOUS**
>
> The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to zero. The fd and offset arguments are ignored; however,
>   **some implementations require fd to be -1 if MAP_ANONYMOUS (or
>   MAP_ANON) is specified,** and portable applications should ensure this.
>   The use of MAP_ANONYMOUS in conjunction with MAP_SHARED is only
>   supported on Linux since kernel 2.4.

It says if `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is specified then we may use `-1` as `fd` which explains your question.